# how can I change the content when browsing a web page?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to write a program to change the content when browsing a web page, and suppose to add  the following feature:

1) to highlight some keywords

2) change the  background of the keywords

3) when mouse move on it, will give a message bubble

I have some ideas, but I am not sure which one will work:

1. write an addon for firefox
2. write an extension for chrome
3. write a proxy using php to change the content of the web page being proxy-ed.
4. inject javascript to the web page
5. other solutions ... ?

which one can solve the problem ? and which one is the best?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: greasemonkey does it for you

Comment: Server side or client side ? PHP / JavaScript ?

Comment: You can use userscripts as they are supported on IE(Sleipnir), Chrome(tampermonkey) and Firefox(greasemonkey) http://userscripts.org/

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Client , if it cannot solved in client side, will try  the server side(using php).

Comment: Server-side or Client-side depends on what kind of data you want to change.

Comment: @JmVerastigue: Not to forget Opera (native) :-)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I want to change the content of any web page, for example: https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/

Comment: Thanks all, will try greasemonkey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 1+4 or 2+4 (or 1+2+4), you'll have to write a script that will be injected to the pages and it can be used as a Firefox Greasemonkey script or a Chorme extension.

Unlike in Firefox where you need Greasemonkey to make scripts work, a simple script file can be used directly as a Chrome extension by dragging it to the extensions window. With some more [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html) on how to organise an extension you can make it a complete Chrome extension.

A sample script that will inject script only when you are on stackoverflow:

**script.user.js**

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("http://stackoverflow.com")!=-1) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = "Hello World! This is my first injected script";
    d.className = "red"; // supposing it's defined, wouldn't hurt anyways
    // otherwise
    d.style.color = "#f00";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

Save your file and drag it to the "extentions" window on Chrome, then reload stackoverflow.

Comment: Chrome has tempermonkey , IE has Sleipnir

Comment: Yes it does, but you still can run scripts directly on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a bookmarklet. They are simply javascript snippets masquerading as bookmarks in a user's bookmark bar. When a user clicks on the bookmark, the javascript code is injected and run on the current website. You wouldn't need to have your users download additional software or be tied down to a particular browser.

Here is an excellent link to get you started
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/